# Overriding $(window).focus( func(){..}) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, overriding

I want to override parent prototype function
`$(window).focus( func(){..})` in javascript and set it to always true, such that

```
$(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {...}
```

always return true.

TRY :
http://jsfiddle.net/ScKbk/

I want this to remain focused permanently. How do I do that

User can leave the webpage say, webpage1 whenever they want, but the variables on the webpage1 tells the server that it is still in focus –

Comment: You can't. There's no way in JS to force constant focus on a browser tab - and that's a *very* good thing. Why do you need this? Sounds like a spam advert feature.

Comment: Can it be made to return true, whenever called by whichever function ?

Comment: Yes, but that won't stop the window from losing focus at all

Comment: Facing similar problem /?

Comment: What do you mean by "return true"? `.on()` is not a boolean function, it doesn't test anything.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok, what's the way ?

Comment: See my first comment

Comment: Think about it, you go to visit some website, and you can never leave, wouldn't that be swell !

Comment: There used to be ways for scripts to do this, but it was abused by malware, so browsers no longer allow it.

Comment: User can leave the webpage1, but the variables on the webpage1 tells the server that it is still in focus

Comment: Why would the server need to know that? Starting to sound like more an X/Y problem

Comment: Ok that's half the story - why does the page tell the server it's in focus? Why do you need that level of synchronicity? Is this a banking app? If not it sounds like a huge waste of resources.

Comment: This is definitely a xy problem, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377